Hagan formula for normal volatility
I am not sure I understand how Hagan normal volatility formula works. Basically I have:
Lognormal volatility of 0.059 (5.9%)
Forward price of the bond 134.5
Bond Strike price 132.5
Option maturity 0.16 years
Normal volatility = 0.059 * (134.5-132.5) / ln ( 134.5/132.5) * ( 1 - 0.059 * 0.059 * 0.16/24) = 7.87
This means that with a 5.9% lognormal volatility I get 787% normal volatility!! I am doing anything wrong?
For the context these data are taken from bond option

what is your underlying? 134.5 is the quote in which unit?

134.5 is the price in euro of the underlying bond

This has nothing to do with Hagan formula but only with what lognormal and normal volatilities mean.
Normal volatilities are highly dependent on the underlying price, where as lognormal volatilities are not.
If your underlying forward is $F=134.5$, at-the-money, the normal vol is approximately $\sigma_N = \sigma_{LN} F$.
Hence the value of 784% is normal for a normal vol, when $\sigma_{LN} \approx 6\%$ and $F=134.5$.
